# PHP exec does not load variables in /etc/environment

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec

I´m using Ubuntu.

I have a PHP script that needs to call a `program`  in shell and get its output.

That `program` uses a shared library, so I need to set up the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. As that program is used system wide, that setup is done on `/etc/environment`  as follows:

```
/etc/environment file:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/shared/library/libmyshared.so
```

If I open a terminal and to look for the code, it is there:

```
$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/shared/library/libmyshared.so
```

Here is the PHP script that needs to call a program:

```
$cmd = "program";
exec ($cmd, $out);
var_dump($out);
```

I´m getting a empty dump and an error on PHP saying that the shared library was not found...

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmyshared.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Well, if I issue in PHP:

```
$cmd = "env;";
exec ($cmd, $out);
var_dump($out);
```

The output show only a small number of apache variables, none that is being used in a normal terminal window.

What may be missing here so that my `exec` command works ?

Help appreciated...

Comment: so where is YOUR shell's ld_lib path getting set? that's not going to apply to the shell that PHP invokes when it's running under a webserver - it'll be using whatever env is set up for the webserver user's shell.

Comment: Also all depends on your distribution release, which PHP SAPI is run, suexec wrappers, if the sample library path actually exists (should be a directory list btw), etc. Why would you manually preload a library for that specific application? Does it even run in a plain terminal session after tampering with the environment settings?

Comment: As said,  my LD_LIB is being set at `/etc/environment`. This was supposed to be loaded system wide.... See System Wide Variable Environments at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables]... And it runs very well on any new terminal opened...